# Passport.js always executing "failureRedirect"

Tags: node.js, registration, passport.js

First of all, I'm very new to Passport.js so maybe this ends up being a very naïve question. I have this as a strategy for the signup:

```
// Configuring Passport
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook');
app.use(expressSession({secret: 'mySecretKey'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

//[...]

  passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
     name : 'name',
     password : 'password',
     email : 'email',
     passReqToCallback : true 
   },
   function(req, username, password, done) {
     findOrCreateUser = function(){
       // find a user in Mongo with provided username
       User.findOne({'name':username},function(err, user) {
         // In case of any error return
         if (err){
           console.log('Error in SignUp: '+err);
           return done(err);
         }
        // already exists
      if (user) {
            console.log('User already exists');
            return done(null, false,
            req.flash('message','User Already Exists'));
         } else {
           // if there is no user with that email
           // create the user
           var newUser = new User();
           // set the user's local credentials
           newUser.name = name;
           newUser.password = createHash(password);
           newUser.email = req.param('email');
           /*newUser.firstName = req.param('firstName');
           newUser.lastName = req.param('lastName');*/

           // save the user
           newUser.save(function(err) {
             if (err){
               console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);
               throw err;
             }
             console.log('User Registration succesful');
             return done(null, newUser);
           });
         }
       });
    };

    // Delay the execution of findOrCreateUser and execute
    // the method in the next tick of the event loop
    process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
  })
 );
```

And this is how I deal with a `POST` on `/register`:

```
/* Handle Registration POST */
app.post('/register', passport.authenticate('signup', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/failure_registration',
  failureFlash : true
}));
```

This *always* brings me to the `failureRedirect` link, instead of the success. The input data is correct, and I'm always using a different user and mail to register. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I don't really understand why it never goes to the `successRedirect`.

Thanks.

EDIT: added the suggestion and corrections by @robertklep, still not working. I'd like to point out that no error is triggered, nor any log printed.

EDIT2: Serialization/deserialization functions:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Comment: Configuration and setup of Passport requires a particular order. Without more information on how you configure the rest of Passport it's difficult to say what the reason might be. Check out [the various example projects](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples) to make sure that your setup looks similar (particularly the order in which the strategy and Express middlewares are set up).

Comment: Added the configuration to the question, you can check it out. Checked multiple examples, they more or less look all the same. Still not working. If you need more code I can provide it.

Comment: Just to make sure, can you remove the `process.nextTick()` (and move the code inside `findOrCreateUser()` up a level)? It's not useful. Also, move the `passport.use('signup', ...)` to _before_ `app.use(passport.*)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately I applied your changes but they did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 12):

I had this same problem, failureRedirect was always being executed

First to diagnose, I used the custom callback method
http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate

```
app.post('/sign_in', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url);
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
        console.log("authenticate");
        console.log(err);
        console.log(user);
        console.log(info);
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Then I could see what the hidden error was

```
authenticate
null
false
{ message: 'Missing credentials' }
```

Which then became easy for me to diagnoise, I was sending JSON in the request rather than FORM fields

Fixed by changing

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

To

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is almost 4 years old, but in case someone runs into the same issue, I used the diagnose from djeeg

```js
app.post('/sign_in', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url);
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
        console.log("authenticate");
        console.log(err);
        console.log(user);
        console.log(info);
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

and I got: 
null
false
'missing credentials'

THE SOLUTION: It turns out I had not used the "name" in my HTML form which meant data wasn't read and that's where the error came from

```html
<input name="email" type="email">
```

That fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

the function `function(req, name, password, email, done)` is wrong. the verify function signature is `function(req, username, password, verified)` when the `passReqToCallback` flag is on.

you're not providing serialization/deserialization functions. This is probably not biting you at the moment but could later on.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.id);
});
```

what I also find interesting is that you use the `authenticate` function to actually create a user. I'd probably create the user and then call passport.login to make them authenticated.

Just my 2 pence :-)

Comment: Thanks, I added the serialization/deserialization functions I already defined to the question. I also removed the email and used username for the `findOne` function. Still not working, nor any log produced.

Answer (score 0):

do you use http or https ? I had the same situation. I fixed it like this

```
app.use(expressSession({....   
   cookie: {
   httpOnly: true,
   secure: false // for http and true for https
 }
}));
```

In my situation passport can't receive cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking method of your form, it must be method = post, in case i mistakenly wrote it as GET method, and took me 3 days to find this, because there was no error